# Is there a psychological effect when you speak badly about a person to another person and then that inadvertently reflects back on you?

Tags: terminology

Suppose one person (Person A) were to speak badly of another person (Person B) in conversation with Person C.

***For example if Person A says that person B is a bad person and that person B is untrustworthy liar and a poor leader.***

My understanding is that there is a psychological affect wherein person C will "reference" and begin to associate person A similarly to person B.

What if any is the term for this reflective or associative effect?

Comment: "begin to associate person A similarly to person C" - did you mean B here instead of C?

Comment: @BryanKrause thanks for catching that. It was a typeO.

Comment: *"My understanding is that there is a psychological affect wherein ..."* – It is your understanding, from where? What have you read which brings you to this?

Comment: To be honest, I read it online a few weeks ago but I could not find the post where I saw originally. That is why I asked, here to confirm what I had read and get pointed to some documentation or resource.
I recalled that the phenomenon had a name but for the life of me I cannot remember the technical name of it.